# Realizing 0/1-polytopes with shortest possible edge lengths

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, polytopes

Has there been something written about the following question?

> **Question:** Given a 0/1-polytope, what is the shortest edge lengths with which this polytope can be realized as a 0/1-polytope.

The realization shall respect the angles of the polytope, so not only the combinatorial type.

**Example.** 
The *regular* $n$-crosspolytope can be realized (asymptotically) with edge length $$\ell\ge \sqrt{n/2},$$
but not shorter.